# Vue add indexed array item as bind and have a dynamically added component react to it

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array, vuejs2, vue-component, bind

I'm trying to react a list of chats to an array and add new chats with a button click. I call the openchat with a id to do it. here is the code. I get the error '_vm.chats is undefined' at startup and the new chat windows are empty on open. Thank you if you get any ideas!!

(app.js)

```
data: {
    chats: ''
}

openchat: function(chatId)
        this.chats = [];
        this.chats[chatId] = [];
        this.chats[chatId].push('simple');
```

(index.blade.php)

```
<chat v-for="(chat, index) in chats" :index="index" v-bind:chats="chats[index]"></chat>
```

(chat.vue)

```
    <template>
                <div v-for="chat in chats" style="overflow: auto;">
                        {{ chat.chat }}
                </div>

    <chat-composer v-bind:chats="chats[chatId]" v-bind:chatId="chatId"></chat-composer>
    </template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['chats', 'userId', 'chatId']
    }
</script>
```

(ChatComposer.vue)

```
props: ['chats', 'userId', 'chatId'],
this.chats[chatId].push(data)
```

Comment: Could you provide a working js fiddle or link to full code?

Comment: I couldn't add the components to jsfiddle. I tried to upload the source to plucker, https://plnkr.co/edit/UKq5CG7jvbwK4s3N0ZS6?p=preview